# Show eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix are larger than eigenvalues of another positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be two symmetric matrices with $A$ being positive semidefinite. Matrix $B$ may not positive semidefinite but all its diagonal entries are positive.

Let $\{\mu_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be eigenvalues of matrix $A + B$ and $\{\nu_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be eigenvalues of matrix $A - B$; both are sorted in decreasing order. I can prove both matrices $A+B$ and $A-B$ are positive semi-definite, and my simulation shows that it is always the case that $\mu_i \geq \nu_i \geq 0$ for any $1 \leq i \leq n$.

I would like to formally prove that $\mu_i \geq \nu_i$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$. So I just wanted to ask for any advice that, in general, what are the sufficient conditions that people commonly use to prove similar things? Any suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Random counterexample: $A=I$ and
$$
B=\pmatrix{1&2&-2\\ 2&1&-2\\ -2&-2&1}.
$$
The sorted eigenvalues of $A+B$ are $6,0,0$ and the sorted eigenvalues of $A-B$ are $2,2,-4$.

Comment: Hi @user1551: Thanks a lot! For my problem, I can show both $A+B$ and $A-B$ are positive semi-definite. Specific to my problem, I feel there are other properties that I can explore. Hence, I would appreciate having a better idea of what tools or methods people usually prove similar things, so I know what properties to check next. Thanks a lot again!